# How to run for loop repeatedly for a set number of cells in Excel using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, for-loop

I am new to using Python to do Excel stuff, so please bear with me. I created an Excel file and I want to start at 0 in a cell and add 10 repeatedly until I reach 350. Then I want to do this again, and again, and again. I start at 0 and add 10 until I reach 350. I figured out this takes up 37 rows. I figured out how to do this once, but I was wondering if there's a way to do this for every 37 rows. I am stuck because I can't change the range after it's been set. Otherwise, I would've added a line at the end of the loop to add 37 to the range.

```
i=0
while i<37:
    for row in range (1,37):
        worksheet.write_number(row, 3, i)
        i=i+10
```

Comment: This is very wonky. You know that `range` takes a step size?

Comment: Could you please show a minimal expected output? Your code seems a bit confusing as is.